# How can I add C++ Source Files and Headers to a C# .Net project?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio

I want to make use of the [HIDAPI](https://github.com/signal11/hidapi/tree/master/windows) library for a home-brewed USB device. Rather than having to compile the VC++ project into its own .dll and reference it in the .Net project I have, I would prefer to just have the code present within the .Net project and be able to reference it directly.

The reason is I want to avoid having a .dll referencing another .dll, and instead just have a single .dll file.

I've done it in reverse, sort of, where I have used a C# class within a C++ program when I was doing some JNI stuff.

Is what I am trying to do here possible? Is there an idiots guide to using C++ in .Net projects somewhere?

Comment: you need to wrap it since .net is managed code and most c++ is unmanaged.

Comment: you could write it in c++/cli or do pinvokes.

Comment: There is facility to merge .NET dlls together: [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx). But you can't  native and managed together.

Comment: Ahhh. Just found another one it's a dup of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854290/combine-native-dll-and-assembly-into-a-single-dll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait, there is a yes answer, but obviously it's completely evil:

[How do I mix C# and C++ code in a single assembly?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2005/05/19/420186.aspx)

If your C++ code is not compiled with /clr:safe (i.e. it is compiled with /clr or /clr:pure), do the following:

1) compile your C++ code into .obj files

2) compile your C# code into a .netmodule, using /AddModule to reference the C++ .obj files

3) link the C# netmodule directly with the C++ object files using the C++ linker to create a mixed language assembly

Also this: [Linking native C++ into C# applications](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/texblog/archive/2007/04/05/linking-native-c-into-c-applications.aspx)

Yeah, don't do that.

Comment: both dead links

Answer (score 3):

> *"Is what I am trying to do here possible?"*

No, it isn't possible this way. These sources can't be compiled within the same project type. You need to have a separate project for the c++/cli assembly, and refer to this one being imported by your c# project.

Comment: Also check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933210/c-cli-why-should-i-use-it for more information.